# vscode: only open the debug tab if breakpoints are set?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is this possible?

Often I just want to run some code and not have the debug window open every time. Ideally, I only want the side debug tab to open if I have a breakpoint set. Otherwise its just taking up screen space and I have to close it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, didnt look hard enough.  Simple setting:

"debug.openDebug": "openOnDebugBreak"